# Tiagra 4503 front derailleur replacement

Tags: road-bike, derailleur, shifting, derailleur-front

I have a bike with a 4503 Shimano setup (Tiagra triple, 9 speed). The front derailleur is broken.

I can quickly get a 105 derailleur (5703) at the local bike shop. I just want to be sure that it is compatible with my shifters, and be sure I can get a clean shifting experience.

Differences between the old and new front derailleur:

- Tiagra vs 105
- 9 speed vs 10 speed

Can anyone confirm the FD-5703 will work on my bike?

Comment: Ok, then I'll probably have to find it online. Which of the derailleurs that are currently on the market would be the best fit? Tiagra FD-4703 or FD-4603 (both 10sp) or Sora FD-3503 or FD-R3030 or FD-R353?

Comment: @DavidW both 5703 and 4503 use the standard road triple 45mm chainline

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus You're right, my bad.  That'll teach me to just take the first google link instead of digging the specs up on Shimano's site.  :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can confirm that the FD-5703 front derailleur works perfectly with the 4503 group set.

I gave it a try anyway. It shifts seemlessly.

Answer (score 5):

Not according to the Shimano compatibility documents.

Tiagra 4500 series appeared about 2006 and 105 5700 series appeared about 2010 so we need to look at the [2010-2011 archived compatibility document](https://productinfo.shimano.com/download/?path=pdfs/archive/2011_Compatibility_en.pdf) from [here](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/archive) and search for 'FD-4503'. The charts say it is only compatible with Tiagra 4503 and Sora 3400 9 speed triple shifters.

To confirm we can search for 'FD-5700', we see it is only compatible with Ultegra 6703 and 105  5703 or 5603 10 speed triple shifters.

However, Shimano is notoriously conservative in its component specifications and compatibility recommendations, so someone may tell you that a 5700 triple front derailleur will work with a 4500 triple shifter - if the two derailleurs use the same actuation ratio they will be basically compatible.

Comment: Ok, then I'll probably have to find it online. Which of the derailleurs that are currently on the market would be the best fit? Tiagra FD-4703 or FD-4603 (both 10sp) or Sora FD-3503 or FD-R3030 or FD-R353?

Comment: Tricky, because 4500 series disappears from the compatibility charts after the 2010-11 document. A 9 speed triple derailleur would be the best bet. Tiagra 4700 is known to use the Shimano 11 speed actuation ratio (at least in the rear) despite being a 10 speed group so I'd definitely stay away from that.

Comment: A 4503 shifter is compatible with a Sora 3400 derailleur. I looked to see if the later Sora 3500 derailleur is compatible with a 3400 shifter, which would allow us to infer a 3500 derailleur is compatible with a 4503 shifter, but there is no compatibility match between 3400 and 3500 in the 2012-13 doc.

Comment: I'd say the FD-R353 is a reasonable bet. Chainline is correct. Comes in 34.9mm band clamp only but you can shim if your seat tube is smaller.